# Should entities from Core Data be strong or weak properties when using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've been confused about core data entities. Since you never allocate them do you need to retain them? When a view controller has an entity as one of its properties should it be **weak** when another view controller assigns the entity but **strong** when the view controller sets the property itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data entity is just an object like any other, so you should follow [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). You `retain` entities when you need them and `release` when you no longer need them.

For example: using sqlite backend, core data will cache loaded data to minimize amount of requests sent to db. But it can't keep all the records in memory and it should understand which entities you use and which don't, so it can release unused and free memory. In case using `weak` properties you can end up with garbage pointer or nil instead of actual object.

Comment: There is direct connection between arc and retain/release as ARC just do it for you behind the scene. Declaring member variable as `strong` means that compiler will retain / release it for you and `weak` means assign.

Comment: Yes, but you say: "You retain entities when you need them and release when you no longer need them." which makes it sound like he should be doing this himself....

Comment: +1 I understood why you explain in retain/release and then jumped into strong/weak for ARC. Thanks for the thoughtful response.